# Why this two rvalue references examples have different behavior?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

**First example**

```
int a = 0;
auto && b = ++a;
++a;
cout << a << b << endl;
```

prints `22`

**Second example**

```
int a = 0;
auto && b = a++;
++a;
cout << a << b << endl;
```

prints `20`

**Question:**
Why in first example `++a` in 3rd line also increments `b`, and why there is no such behavior in second example?

**Update:** [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315826/can-i-use-rvalue-to-temporary-is-it-ub-or-not) arised.

Comment: I'll give you a hint - `a` isn't an rvalue.

Comment: @erip Yes, I know, but what is the difference in two examples for `b`?

Comment: In the second example `b` gets the value of `a` without incrementing it before, like in the first example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because pre-increment (`++a`) first increments the value of `a`, stores the result, and *then* returns the reference to `a`. Now `a` and `b` effectively point to the same object.

Post-increment (`a++`), however, first stores the current value of `a` in a temporary, increments `a`, and returns this temporary - to which your rvalue ref points. `a` and `b` point to different objects, more specifically - `b` is a temporary holding the value of `a` prior to incrementing.

This is the reason why it's encouraged to use `++it` over `it++` for iterators and other complex objects that define increment / decrement: the latter creates a temporary copy and thus *may* be slower.

Comment: Is it UB to use `b` after `a++` in second example?

Comment: And why in first case there is no temporary? Why `auto && b = a++` is not an equivalent to `auto && b = a; a++`?

Comment: @vladon: I _think_ that the temporary will live until the reference to it goes out of scope, meaning it's not UB, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @vladon: Say `a` was `0`. Then `a++` must return `0`, and `a` must become `1`. If it was implemented the way you suggested, you wouldn't get the `0` value. `a++` doesn't return `a`, it returns a **copy** of `a`.

Comment: @vladon You shouldn't add a second question to your original. Mark an answer and ask a new question.

Comment: (Cannot know why, but I cannot mention you in answer with at-sign...) Ok, why then `++a` returns not a copy of `a` (already incremented), but `a` itself? And I think it's UB to use ref to temporary returned by `a++`...

Comment: @erip Ok, I'll do it.

Comment: @vladon: because the standard says `++a` returns a reference :) Now, *why* it's designed this way is a different question. I think it's just both faster (no copying involved) and gives additional flexibility (you can keep chaining calls on the `++` result).

Comment: @vladon: and the reason you can't mention me here, I think, is because I get notifications of any comments on my answer anyway. Mentioning me on my posts would be redundant.

Comment: @erip: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315826/can-i-use-rvalue-to-temporary-is-it-ub-or-not

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `++a` is an lvalue, however `a++` is not. This is specified by C++14 [expr.pre.incr]/1:

> The operand of prefix `++` is modified by adding 1 [...] The
>   operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. [...] The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue

and [expr.post.incr]/1:

> [...] The result is a prvalue.

---

Now we consider `auto && b = ++a;` . `++a` is an lvalue. `auto&&` is a forwarding reference. Forwarding references can actually bind to lvalues: the `auto` may itself deduce to a reference type. This code deduces to `int &b = ++a;`.

When a reference is bound to an lvalue of the same type, the reference binds directly, so `b` becomes another name for `a`.

---

In the second example, `auto && b = a++;`, `a++` is a prvalue. This means it doesn't have an associated address and it's no longer any relation to the variable `a`. This line has the same behaviour as `++a; auto && b = (a + 0);` would.

Firstly, since `a++` is a prvalue, `auto&&` deduces to `int&&`. (i.e. `auto` deduces to `int`).  When a reference of non-class type is bound to a prvalue, a temporary object is copy-initialized from the value. This object has its lifetime extended to match the reference.

So `b` in the second case is bound to a different object from `a`, a "temporary" int (which is not really so temporary, since it lasts as long as `b` does).

The reference binding rules are in [dcl.init.ref].

Answer (score 1):

In the second case (post-increment) b actually references the temporary created for (a++), so the increments do not affect b.